# Extracting JSON and using it in if condition

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I need to add a condition in my thread where my next HTTP Request will execute only if the previous response has message message that says 'You can proceed with the booking.'

[first response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuBdf.png)

I tried adding regular expression extractor to get MessageInfo using the below expression.

`"MessageInfo": "(.*?)"`

I also tried with JSON extractor using below json path expression:

`$..MessageInfo`

Below is the Expression that i added in if condition:

[if condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFLMJ.png)

However, my execution stops after the first response and does not move into the if condition. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [Function or Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which resolves to `true` in the If Controller in order to be able to run its children. You're giving a string which isn't equal to `true` therefore If Controller's children are never run

Therefore you need to use your expression in i.e. [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3)

```
${__jexl3("${MessageInfo}"=="You can proceed with the booking.",)}
```

[image]

More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller)